How do I inject dependencies on Hangfire Job initiated by BackgroudService?
I have a .net Project which needs to run custom logic on Cron.
Here's my Code:
builder.Services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
    .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
       .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
          .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
             .UseSqlServerStorage(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection")));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyCustomDbContext>(o =>
     o.UseSqlServer(
         builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection"),
         options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure()));

// ...other dependencies
builder.Service.AddScoped<IFooService, FooService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<MyCustomJob>();


public class MyCustomJob : IHostedService
{
  private readonly IFooService _fooService;

  public MyCustomJob (IFooService foo)
  {
      _fooService = foo;
  }

  public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
      RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Do Something", () => _fooService.doSomething(), Cron.Minutely);
      return;
  }

  public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
      RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists("Do Something");
      return;
  }
}



public class FooService: IFooService
{
    ILogger<FooService> _logger;
    INugetService _nugetService;

    public FooService(ILogger<FooService> logger, InugetService nugetService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _nugetService = nugetService;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Doing Something at {DateTime.UtcNow} time");
        var result = _nugetService.do();
        //something extra
        if (err)
        {
          throw Exception;
        }
        return;
    }
}

Basically fooService invokes another layer of classes which are provided by a nuget package this includes the DB context as well.
Now the problem is that when _fooService.doSomething() is invoked by hangfire, It no longer seem to have the db context throughout the trace.
I have tried the solutions that are mentioned over here What is an correct way to inject db context to Hangfire Recurring job?

What do you mean ‘does not seem’? Does nugetService have a value? Please give us more detail

Why SO solution do not work for you? You have to create Scope and DO NOT inject IFooService into MyCustomJob, inject IServiceProvider or IServiceScopeFactory and request this service from them. And do not forget to dispose after usage.

where is registration for your INugetService ? Hangfire will resolve all of your dependencies if they are correctly registered.
